# SQL query for picking consecutive time sets

Tags: sql-server-2008

Data: 
Here is sample table(TableA) data

```
ID  StartTime               EndTime
1   2012-03-22 06:00:00.000     2012-03-22 06:30:00.000
2   2012-03-22 06:15:00.000     2012-03-22 06:45:00.000
3   2012-03-22 06:30:00.000     2012-03-22 07:00:00.000
4   2012-03-22 06:45:00.000     2012-03-22 07:15:00.000
5   2012-03-22 07:00:00.000     2012-03-22 07:30:00.000
6   2012-03-22 07:15:00.000     2012-03-22 07:45:00.000
8   2012-03-22 07:30:00.000     2012-03-22 08:00:00.000
9   2012-03-22 07:45:00.000     2012-03-22 08:15:00.000
10  2012-03-22 08:00:00.000     2012-03-22 08:30:00.000
11  2012-03-22 08:15:00.000     2012-03-22 08:45:00.000
12  2012-03-22 08:30:00.000     2012-03-22 09:00:00.000
13  2012-03-22 08:45:00.000     2012-03-22 09:15:00.000
14  2012-03-22 09:00:00.000     2012-03-22 09:30:00.000
15  2012-03-22 09:15:00.000     2012-03-22 09:45:00.000
16  2012-03-22 09:30:00.000     2012-03-22 10:00:00.000
```

Requirement:
Get consecutive time sets for a given time range. e.g. time range:06:00 to 08:00

Expected Output:

```
ID  StartTime               EndTime
1   2012-03-22 06:00:00.000     2012-03-22 06:30:00.000
3   2012-03-22 06:30:00.000     2012-03-22 07:00:00.000
5   2012-03-22 07:00:00.000     2012-03-22 07:30:00.000
8   2012-03-22 07:30:00.000     2012-03-22 08:00:00.000
```

Question:
Is it possible to get the expected output using sql query? i don't want to use loops.

i came up with this, but it only filter first non-consecutive row.

```
SELECT *
 FROM TableA TableA_OUTER (nolock) 
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),EndTime,114) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CAST('08:00' AS DATETIME),114)
AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),StartTime,114) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CAST('06:00' AS DATETIME),114) OR EXISTS 
(SELECT NULL from TableA TableA_INNER (nolock) 
where  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),TableA_OUTER.StartTime,114) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),TableA_INNER.EndTime,114)
))
```

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: why shouldn't your query return records 2, 4 and 6?

Comment: Thank for looking into this. StarTime is the key for first record selection, for 2 starting time is 6:15. my input is 6:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
-- Create table

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

--insert sample data
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(1   ,'2012-03-22 06:00:00.000',     '2012-03-22 06:30:00.000' )
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(2   ,'2012-03-22 06:15:00.000',     '2012-03-22 06:45:00.000' )
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(3   ,'2012-03-22 06:30:00.000',     '2012-03-22 07:00:00.000' )
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(4   ,'2012-03-22 06:45:00.000',     '2012-03-22 07:15:00.000' )
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(5   ,'2012-03-22 07:00:00.000',     '2012-03-22 07:30:00.000' )
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(6   ,'2012-03-22 07:15:00.000',     '2012-03-22 07:45:00.000' )
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(8   ,'2012-03-22 07:30:00.000',     '2012-03-22 08:00:00.000' )
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(9   ,'2012-03-22 07:45:00.000',     '2012-03-22 08:15:00.000' )
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(10  ,'2012-03-22 08:00:00.000',     '2012-03-22 08:30:00.000' )
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(11  ,'2012-03-22 08:15:00.000',     '2012-03-22 08:45:00.000' )
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(12  ,'2012-03-22 08:30:00.000',     '2012-03-22 09:00:00.000' )
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(13  ,'2012-03-22 08:45:00.000',     '2012-03-22 09:15:00.000' )
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(14  ,'2012-03-22 09:00:00.000',     '2012-03-22 09:30:00.000' )
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(15  ,'2012-03-22 09:15:00.000',     '2012-03-22 09:45:00.000' )
Insert Into TableA (ID,StartTime,EndTime) values(16  ,'2012-03-22 09:30:00.000',     '2012-03-22 10:00:00.000' )

 --query

Declare @AnchorElement int
Set @AnchorElement = (Select top 1 ID  from TableA 
where '2012-03-22 06:00:00.000' 
between StartTime and EndTime
Order by StartTime
)
;


 With ListStartingAtDate (ID,  StartTime, EndTime ,Level ) as
    (
        -- Anchor Timeframe definition
        select ID,  StartTime, EndTime , 0 as Level From TableA 
            --Where ID = @AnchorElement
            -- StartTime has to be matched exactly
            WHERE StartTime = '2012-03-22 06:00:00.000' 
        UNION ALL 
        -- Recursive Timeframe definition
        select a.ID,  a.StartTime, a.EndTime ,  Level +1 
        From TableA a
        INNER JOIN ListStartingAtDate b
        ON a.StartTime = b.EndTime

    )

    select  * from ListStartingAtDate
    where StartTime >= '2012-03-22 06:00:00.000' and EndTime <= '2012-03-22 08:00:00.000'
```

Comment: @MalcomFrexner : Thank you for writing this, this definitely gives the outcome what i am expecting for correct input values, is it possible to show no rows when input starttime or endtime is not in the table? For e.g. if starttime is given as 6:10, it still shows rows starting from 6:30. same problem with endtime. Please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: I changed the query to match the starttime. I still have to think about endtime. There might only be a not so elegant solutiobn (like looking in the result table for the enddate)

Comment: I think running your query only when endtime is matched should solve my problem.